Select specific columns according to a condition
I'm working on metabase and I have a table like this



id
type_id
AMOUNT
format_Date




id_1
t1
13
01-2024


id_1
t1
12
02-2024


id_2
t2
13
03-2024


id_2
t2
12
06-2024


id_1
t1
25
13-2024


id_2
t2
25
13-2024



This table shows the amount of money that was accumulated during an entire month, but it also shows the total amount (the rows where the format_Date prefix is 13).
This table is the result of others, so even the format_date values ​​will change.
From that table I want to create one with the pivoted dates, but only show the columns up to the month of the current year.
For example, if we are in October there will still be no data with the format_date prefix >10. Initially I was using this query:
SELECT
  type_id,
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '01' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS january,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '02' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS february,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '03' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS march,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '04' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS april,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '05' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS may,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '06' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS june,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '07' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS july,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '08' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS august,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '09' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS september,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '10' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS october,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '11' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS november,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '12' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS december,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEFT(format_Date, 2) = '13' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS year_amount
FROM
  data_pivoted 
GROUP BY
  id,type_id,amount

but with that query I will show all the months, even those that are after the current month where all the values ​​will be zero

You can only add/remove a column from a query if the query itself is built dynamically. Other than that you can control the result on the client side (app?) or return null for that value, still shows the column though.

One thing I would recommend yourself is to ask: Why is hiding the column important? I'm almost sure you are approaching the wrong solution for this question by the way.

Can you add the desired output table? An example with data? With that in hand, we can create a query that is closer to the desired format
